# Address Table Scheme for Geolocation services

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, database-design, geolocation, google-geocoder

I have a SQL database with tables such as Stores, Users, etc.

Both Store and User, as well as other entities, have an Address.

I am considering creating an Addresses table for all Addresses:

```
Users
--------
UserId (PK)
AddressId (FK)
Name

Addresses
--------  
AddressID (PK)
CountryID (FK) -> I have a table Countries with all Countries
Street
PostalCode
Locality
Region
Latitude
Longitude
```

When a user is filling the Profile I would have an input to type the address.

I would like to use Google Geocoding API to convert the typed address into its fields and save it into the database including Latitude and Longitude.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

I have a few questions:

1. Is my Address table scheme appropriate for this?
2. I am planing to use Google Geocoding API so should I store the PlaceId then Google returns on my database?

My main objectives are:

1. Convert the address typed by the user into address fields and save to database;
2. By having the Latitude and Longitude of the address type by the user in my database I will be able to search them by location. 
   Example: Get users of my application in a radius of 20 km of a London address.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about to separate the HouseNumber? Some external Services or API's require this. Its easier to concat this fields if required.

There is a geography Datatype for geolocations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017
With this type you can query the Database performantly with some geo functions e.g. distance between two points.

I wont save the Google-API result directly. Use your own required schema.

If you use the geography type you can query with Long/Lat and Distance by radius.

Comment: So you suggest to save the Addresses using my schema in the database. When creating a new address call Google API to get the latitude and longitude and save those 2 values as geography in my database. Now I can use my own database to filter by location. If this is what you meant that is also my idea, maybe if i did not explain well.

Comment: When a user types some address in ONE input I will used Google Maps autocomplete that will snap to, for example, to "20 Oxford Street, London, UK" then I will get address fields and latitude / longitude of that address from google and store it in my own schema.

Comment: Yes, having a field for house number might be a good idea. I didn't add it as is a field that varies so much so I didn't know if I could normalize it. I am looking for the schema that some of those services use as well as ISO schemas if there are any.

Comment: You are on the right way.
I would just change the schema:

Latitude
Longitude 

->

Location geography